# How to get input text value with a loop if you have txtbox1, txtbox2, txtbox3?

Tags: asp.net, for-loop

I made a table with input text fields with ids of

```
        <td> <INPUT id="txtName1" type="text" runat="server" /> </td>
        <td> <INPUT id="txtDescription1" type="text" runat="server" /> </td>
        <td> <INPUT id="txtColNum1" type="text" runat="server" /> </td>
        <td> <INPUT id="txtColW1" type="text" runat="server" /> </td>
        <td> <INPUT id="txtType1" type="text" runat="server" /> </td>
        <td> <INPUT id="txtFormula1" type="text" runat="server" /> </td>
        <td> <INPUT id="txtCost1" type="text" runat="server" /> </td>
        <td> <INPUT id="txtCostFormula1" type="text" runat="server" /> </td>
        <td> <INPUT id="txtPullDown1" type="text" runat="server" /> </td>
        <td> <INPUT id="chkLock1" type="checkbox" runat="server" /> </td>
        <td> <INPUT id="chkHideQ1" type="checkbox" runat="server" /> </td>
        <td> <INPUT id="chkHideW1" type="checkbox" runat="server" /> </td>
```

and have a javascript to add rows dynamically, incrementing the digit of the id such as

txtName2, txtDescription2, txtColNum2 and so on...

Moreover, I'm saving the data to SQL using vb.net with the code below

```
Protected Sub btnSaveTemplate_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnSaveTemplate.Click

        SqlCMData.InsertParameters("categoryName").DefaultValue = txtCategory1.Value
        SqlCMData.InsertParameters("productName").DefaultValue = txtName1.Value
        SqlCMData.InsertParameters("productDescription").DefaultValue = txtDescription1.Value
        SqlCMData.InsertParameters("colNum").DefaultValue = txtColNum1.Value
        SqlCMData.InsertParameters("colW").DefaultValue = txtColW1.Value
        SqlCMData.InsertParameters("type").DefaultValue = txtType1.Value
        SqlCMData.InsertParameters("formula").DefaultValue = txtFormula1.Value
        SqlCMData.InsertParameters("cost").DefaultValue = txtCost1.Value
        SqlCMData.InsertParameters("costFormula").DefaultValue = txtCostFormula1.Value
        SqlCMData.InsertParameters("pullDown").DefaultValue = txtPullDown1.Value
        SqlCMData.InsertParameters("lock").DefaultValue = chkLock1.Checked
        SqlCMData.InsertParameters("hideQ").DefaultValue = chkHideQ1.Checked
        SqlCMData.InsertParameters("hideW").DefaultValue = chkHideW1.Checked
        SqlCMData.Insert()

End Sub
```

My problem is, how can I have a for loop get all the values including the other rows with the id's digit have been incremented such as txtCategory**2**?

Comment: Controls you are adding at client side (using js) won't be available on the server.

Answer (score 0):

Lets say the highest number you get to is 10, you could just have a loop.
Here's and example in quasi-code.

```
for (i = 1; i < 10; i++)
{
   INSERT txtCategory + i;
   INSERT txtName + i;
   INSERT txtDescription + i;
   .
   .
   .
   .
   .
   .
   INSERT chkHideW + i;
}
```

Obviously the INSERT is just an abbreviation for inserting it to a MySQL table. This should allow you to insert all the elements i times, i being the highest numbered suffix you reached. I can't promise this will work but I hope it helps, at least with the logic behind it.